# want to join three table

Tags: mysql, nodes

I have write query for join three tables but it thow error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

This is my query

```
var userquery = 'SELECT Device_Id,DATE_FORMAT(Date, "%d/%m/%Y") AS Date,Time,Session_Status,Associate_id,Patient_ID,Session_Id,Applicator_Type,Intensity,Motor_Frequency,CONCAT(PEMF_Min_Freq,"-",PEMF_Max_Freq)as PEMF,Waveform,Treatment_Duration, CONCAT(therapy_session_info.Patient_iid,"-",patient_info.first_name)as patient_info,patient_info.condition1, user_device_mapping.device_id from therapy_session_info INNER JOIN patient_info ON  therapy_session_info.Patient_iid=patient_info.patient_id INNER JOIN user_device_mapping ON therapy_session_info.Device_Id=user_device_mapping.device_id where doctor_id=? and Date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) '; 

one: function (callback) {
                         db.query('SELECT doctor_id from user_info where email_id=?', [name], function (error, rows, fields, next) {
                            for (var i in rows) {
                                console.log('----------hhh--111-' + rows[i].doctor_id);
                            }

                            db.query(userquery,[rows[i].doctor_id], function (error, rows, fields, next) {
                                console.log('length--' + rows.length);
                                callback(error, rows);
                                console.log('report fetching error---'+rows);
                            });

                        });
                    }
```

This is  therapy_session_info table

```
| id | Device_Id | Date       | Time     | Session_Status | associate_id | Patient_iid | Session_Id | Applicator_Type | Intensity | Motor_Frequency | PEMF_Min_Freq | PEMF_Max_Freq | Waveform | Treatment_Duration |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+----------+--------------------+
|  2 |      0001 | 2016-11-30 | 15:11:05 | C              |         0001 |        0001 |        123 | M               |        10 |              15 |             4 |             8 | 1        |                  5 |
|  3 |      0003 | 2016-11-30 | 15:11:05 | C              |         0002 |        0002 |        456 | P               |        12 |             100 |             7 |            14 | 3        |                  8 |
```

***This is  patient_info table***

```
| id | patient_id | doctor_id | first_name | middle_name | last_name | age | gender | weight | condition1       | diagnose         | pcontact_no | scontact_no | email_id                | address | link | comment | status | creation_date       | photo                                                                                    | modified            |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+-----+--------+--------+------------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+---------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       0001 |      0054 | sunita     | b           | kadam     | 26  | Female | 45     | Frozen shoulder  | Select Diagnose  | 9503709388  |             | sunitakadam88@gmail.com |         |      |         |      1 | 2016-11-25 14:35:28 | /home/smartleaven/PTD_NEW/UserPortal/uploads/images/8961a2ac13575fce548715410d006c3a.png | 2016-11-25 14:53:46 |
|  2 |       0002 |      0054 | nilam      | m           | mane      | 26  | Female | 44     | Lower back pain  | Select Diagnose  | 9854646464  | NULL        | nilammmm@yahoo.com      | NULL    | NULL | NULL    |      1 | 2016-11-25 14:38:19 | NULL                                                                                     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
```

***This is user_device_mapping table***

```
+----+----------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| id | doctor_id            | device_id | creation_date       |
+----+----------------------+-----------+---------------------+
|  2 | 0069 - rahul kadam   | 0002      | 2016-11-28 17:11:14 |
|  4 | 0063 - Sunita Kadam  | 0001      | 2016-11-28 17:42:35 |
|  5 | 0063 - Sunita Kadam  | 0003      | 2016-11-28 17:50:21 |
+----+----------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Your loop reads `for (var i in rows)` and within the loop you are using `rows` instead of `i`.

Comment: Also, immediately after the loop you are still referencing `i`.

Comment: var userquery = 'SELECT Device_Id,DATE_FORMAT(Date, "%d/%m/%Y") AS Date,Time,Session_Status,Associate_id,Patient_ID,Session_Id,Applicator_Type,Intensity,Motor_Frequency,CONCAT(PEMF_Min_Freq,"-",PEMF_Max_Freq)as PEMF,Waveform,Treatment_Duration, CONCAT(therapy_session_info.Patient_iid,"-",patient_info.first_name)as patient_info,patient_info.condition1 from therapy_session_info INNER JOIN patient_info ON  therapy_session_info.Patient_iid=patient_info.patient_id  where patient_info.doctor_id=? and Date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)  Group By patient_id';  but this query work fine.

Comment: Please edit/update your question with the above contents, formatted(!), and with the results it generates.

Comment: query is same.main difference is if i join two table it work fine and display result as required but now i want to join three table and its not working if i add one more join in same query

Comment: Post the query that does not work (formatted please).